# Inaccurate while loop timing in Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am trying to log data at with a high sampling rate using a Raspberry Pi 3 B+. In order to achieve a fixed sampling rate, I am delaying the while loop, but I always get a sample rate that is a little less than I specify.

For 2500 Hz I get ~2450 Hz

For 5000 Hz I get ~4800 Hz

For 10000 Hz I get ~9300 Hz

Here is the code that I use to delay the while loop:

```
import time

count=0
while True:
    sample_rate=5000

    time_start=time.perf_counter()
    count+=1
    while (time.perf_counter()-time_start) < (1/sample_rate):
        pass

    if count == sample_rate:
        print(1/(time.perf_counter()-time_start))
        count=0
```

I have also tried updating to Python 3.7 and used time.perf_counter_ns(), but it does not make a difference.

Comment: Executing that while loop takes time. Since Python is an interpreted language, there is overhead in interpreting the code. If you want to achieve a higher accuracy than that, best to write the sampling code in a compiled language.

Comment: Why do a tight loop, why not just delay? And, if you read the time before starting the loop, then increment it with your desired delay each time, the jitter will only be around the correct intervals, no extra uncertainty cause by reading the time every time round the loop. But yes linux on Pi isn't exactly a realtime platform, your timings will vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is because your code is using the real time each time in the loop when it starts each delay for the period duration - and so time spent in untimed code and jitter due to OS multitasking accumulates, reducing the overall period below what you want to achieve.

To greatly increase the timing accuracy, use the fact that each loop "should" finish at the period (1/sample_rate) after it should have started - and maintain that start time as an absolute calculation rather than the real time, and wait until the period after that absolute start time, and then there is no drift in the timing.

I put your timing into timing_orig and my revised code using absolute times into timing_new - and results are below.

```
import time

def timing_orig(ratehz,timefun=time.clock):
    count=0
    while True:
        sample_rate=ratehz

        time_start=timefun()
        count+=1
        while (timefun()-time_start) < (1.0/sample_rate):
            pass

        if count == ratehz:
            break

def timing_new(ratehz,timefun=time.clock):
    count=0
    delta = (1.0/ratehz)
    # record the start of the sequence of timed periods
    time_start=timefun()
    while True:
        count+=1
        # this period ends delta from "now" (now is the time_start PLUS  a number of deltas)
        time_next = time_start+delta
        # wait until the end time has passed
        while timefun()<time_next:
            pass
        # calculate the idealised "now" as delta from the start of this period
        time_start = time_next
        if count == ratehz:
            break

def timing(functotime,ratehz,ntimes,timefun=time.clock):
    starttime = timefun()
    for n in range(int(ntimes)):
        functotime(ratehz,timefun)
    endtime = timefun()
#   print endtime-starttime
    return ratehz*ntimes/(endtime-starttime)

if __name__=='__main__':
    print "new 5000",timing(timing_new,5000.0,10.0)
    print "old 5000",timing(timing_orig,5000.0,10.0)
    print "new 10000",timing(timing_new,10000.0,10.0)
    print "old 10000",timing(timing_orig,10000.0,10.0)
    print "new 50000",timing(timing_new,50000.0,10.0)
    print "old 50000",timing(timing_orig,50000.0,10.0)
    print "new 100000",timing(timing_new,100000.0,10.0)
    print "old 100000",timing(timing_orig,100000.0,10.0)
```

Results:

```
new 5000 4999.96331002
old 5000 4991.73952992
new 10000 9999.92662005
old 10000 9956.9314274
new 50000 49999.6477761
old 50000 49591.6104893
new 100000 99999.2172809
old 100000 94841.227219
```

Note I didn't use time.sleep() because it introduced too much jitter. Also, note that even though this minimal example shows very accurate timing even up to 100khz on my Windows laptop, if you put more code into the loop than there is time to execute, the timing will run correspondingly slow.

Apologies I used Python 2.7 which doesn't have the very convenient time.perf_counter() function - add an extra parameter timefun=time.perf_counter() to each of the calls to timing()

Answer (score 1):

I think you can fix this pretty easily by rearranging your code as such:

```
import time

count=0 
sample_rate=5000
while True:
    time_start=time.perf_counter()

    # do all the real stuff here

    while (time.perf_counter()-time_start) < (1/sample_rate):
        pass
```

This way python does the waiting after you execute the code, rather than before, so the time the interpreter takes to run it will not be added to your sample rate. As danny said, it's an interpreted language so that might introduce timing inconsistencies, but this way should at least decrease the effect you are seeing.

Edit for proof that this works:

```
import sys
import time

count=0 
sample_rate=int(sys.argv[1])
run_start = time.time()

while True:
    time_start=time.time()

    a = range(10)
    b = range(10)
    for x in a:
        for y in b:
            c = a+b
    count += 1
    if count == sample_rate*2:
        break
    while (time.time()-time_start) < (1.0/sample_rate):
        pass

real_rate = sample_rate*2/(time.time()-run_start)
print real_rate, real_rate/sample_rate
```

So the testing code does a solid amount of random junk for 2 seconds and then prints the real rate and the percentage of the actual rate that turns out to be. Here's some results:

```
~ ><> python t.py 1000
999.378471674 0.999378471674
~ ><> python t.py 2000
1995.98713838 0.99799356919
~ ><> python t.py 5000
4980.90553757 0.996181107514
~ ><> python t.py 10000
9939.73553783 0.993973553783
~ ><> python t.py 40000
38343.706669 0.958592666726
```

So, not perfect. But definitely better than a ~700Hz drop at a desired 10000. The accepted answer is definitely the right one.

Comment: Can you demonstrate that your rearrangement actually produces more accurate timing? How much more accurate?