# frame rate not correct in videos

Tags: opencv, frame-rate

I have a 12 sec video in 25 fps. When I play the video in 25 fps in opencv the video becomes 16 sec. I get the fps by using 
fps = get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) and then I set waitKey(1000/fps) but the video plays to slow...

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
start = time.time()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("hackerman.mp4")
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
print(fps)
while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        frame_new = frame
    else:
        end = time.time()
    # frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # turn video gray

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.namedWindow('frame', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame_new)

    k = cv2.waitKey(int(round(1000/fps))) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:         # wait for ESC key to exit
        break
    elif cv2.getWindowProperty("frame", 0) == -1:
        break


print(end-start)
# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You are sequentially reading and displaying each frame then pausing for 40ms - so the next frame isn't captured until the previous one has been displayed, i.e. the overall speed will be slower than 25fps. How quickly does it run if you don't use `waitKey(1000/fps)`?

Comment: @barny You have to use waitkey or the video wont show, the script runs in 1.8 sec.
If I set waitkey(1) it takes 3.8 sec
Using waitkey(1000/25) it takes 13.8 sec
so basically the video is 1.8 sec too long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that not unreasonably cap.read() is reading faster than the frame rate, which would be highly desirable if you were processing the frames rather than displaying them - so in your application you need to add a delay using e.g. `time.sleep()` or in your case `waitKey()` and this must be calculated to hit the frame rate 25fps.

For most precise 25fps, base the time for the end of the next frame on the overall starting time, like this (untested):

```
frameref_ms = int(time.time()*1000)
frametime_ms = int(1000/fps)

while True:
    # update frameref to end frame period from now (regardless of how long reading and displaying the frame takes)
    frameref_ms += frametime_ms
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        frame_new = frame
    else:
        end = time.time()
    # frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # turn video gray

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.namedWindow('frame', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame_new)
    # wait for a keypress or the time needed to finish the frame duration
    k = cv2.waitKey(frameref_ms-int(time.time()*1000)) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:         # wait for ESC key to exit
        break
    elif cv2.getWindowProperty("frame", 0) == -1:
        break
```

This technique of having an absolute time to finish the display/read the next frame means that the frame rate will be exact, automatically compensating for multi-tasking other OS tasks as long as those other tasks don't take so much CPU that your code hardly runs, if you hit that problem I guess you'll have to increase the priority of Python which will slow the other programs down. I've used this method in timing sampling for temperature/vibration measurements and it works very well. See the same technique in one of my answers [Inaccurate while loop timing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50471895/inaccurate-while-loop-timing-in-python/50477494#50477494)

If you were being really careful/pessimistic you'd also check that `waitKey()` isn't being given a negative delay in the case where the frame read+display took longer than the frame period.

Comment: thanks! this works great! what a smart solution. As you said I guess one could get an even better estimate if one accounts for the time it takes to execute this 


    `k = cv2.waitKey(frameref_ms-int(time.time()*1000)) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:         # wait for ESC key to exit
        break
    elif cv2.getWindowProperty("frame", 0) == -1:
        break`

but the difference seems to be 2 ms for the whole video so not that big of a deal

Comment: The variation in delay of the waitkey call only affects jitter of a single frame display duration which you won't notice. You could improve sub-millisecond accuracy by working in microseconds and only converting to milliseconds in the `waitKey()` call, but don't expect too much - your Linux/Windows host isn't a realtime system.

Comment: I checked the time it took to go through the above code and it was around 1 ms, so I used waitkey(frameref_ms-int(time.time()*1000)-1).
Now my video is 12.0004 sec, without removing 1 ms from waitkey it was around 12.001 sec :)

Comment: On the final iteration the time to execute waitKey will add to the overall time, but e.g. a 120s video would have been 120.001 seconds, i.e. there won't be a rate error due to executing waitKey. 1ms is completely negligible for Linux/Windows playing a video to a human.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was very helpful to me. Only found the basic video display version everywhere. Although I am noticing I just picked the wrong tool with opencv for a multi media application. Have a good day, and thanks again!