# Timer drift in multithreading Python program

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi

I´m working currently on a Datalogger for a project. The Datalogger should read Data from two different CAN-Bus System on truck mounted access platform, decode the raw data and store it periodically in a json file which will be uploaded to a blob storage before the units gets shutdown . I´m using a Hardware which is based on a raspberry pi and programmed it in Python 3.7.
Everything is working fine except the periodically storing of the data. Creating and storing the data in the json file start well and do it in 100ms steps after a minute you start seeing a drift in the time between two data points. If you run the code for hours is getting up to minutes between the datapoints.

I understand that Linux is not a RTOS, but it should be possible to save the data in 100ms steps. So is my approach the wrong?

I tried to use threading.Event instead of sleep, I tried also to run it as mutliple processes instead threads.

Here the code from the function I have the issue with:

```
def create_json_file():
    global FILE_INITIALIZED
    global FILE_NAME
    once = bool

    try:
        while not stop_create.is_set():
            if not store_data:
                next_call = time.time()

            if  store_data == True:
                if not once:
                    next_call = time.time()
                    once = True
                # Calculate the offset taking into account daylight saving time
                utc_offset_sec = time.altzone if time.localtime().tm_isdst else time.timezone
                utc_offset = datetime.timedelta(seconds=-utc_offset_sec)
                timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone(offset=utc_offset)).isoformat()
                tmp_json_dict = {}
                tmp_json_dict['deviceId'] = DEVICE_ID
                tmp_json_dict['timestamp'] = timestamp
                tmp_json_dict.update(processed_data)

                if FILE_INITIALIZED == False:
                    first_json_dict = []
                    first_json_dict.append(tmp_json_dict)
                    FILE_NAME = './storage/' + DEVICE_ID + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("_%Y%m%d_%H%M.json")
                #/home/pi/Test
                if FILE_INITIALIZED == False:
                    with open(FILE_NAME,"w+") as outputfile:
                        json.dump(first_json_dict,outputfile,indent=4,sort_keys=False)
                        FILE_INITIALIZED = True
                        first_json_dict.clear()
                else:
                    with open(FILE_NAME, "r+") as file:
                        file_data = json.load(file)
                        file_data.append(tmp_json_dict)
                        file.seek(0)
                        json.dump(file_data, file, indent=4)
                
                next_call = next_call + INTERVAL_TIME
                time.sleep(abs(next_call - time.time()))

    except Exception as err:
        logging.exception(err)
        if not stop_create.is_set():
            # Only log exception if we were not going to stop the thread
            # When quitting, the main thread calls close() on the serial device
            # and read() may throw an exception. We don't want to display it as
            # we're stopping the script anyway
            global thread_exception_file
            thread_exception_file = sys.exc_info()
```

Here is the output with drift after a time:

```
[
    {
        "deviceId": "Prototype_FieldTest_P300KS_Facelift",
        "timestamp": "2020-11-28T22:24:13.480148+01:00"
    },
    {
        "deviceId": "Prototype_FieldTest_P300KS_Facelift",
        "timestamp": "2020-11-28T22:24:13.580144+01:00"
    },
    {
        "deviceId": "Prototype_FieldTest_P300KS_Facelift",
        "timestamp": "2020-11-28T22:24:13.679995+01:00"
    },
    {
        "deviceId": "Prototype_FieldTest_P300KS_Facelift",
        "timestamp": "2020-11-28T22:24:13.780075+01:00"
    },
    {
        "deviceId": "Prototype_FieldTest_P300KS_Facelift",
        "timestamp": "2020-11-28T22:24:13.880101+01:00"
    },
...
...
...
    {
        "deviceId": "Prototype_FieldTest_P300KS_Facelift",
        "timestamp": "2020-11-28T22:25:20.078147+01:00"
    },
    {
        "deviceId": "Prototype_FieldTest_P300KS_Facelift",
        "timestamp": "2020-11-28T22:25:20.316632+01:00"
    },
    {
        "deviceId": "Prototype_FieldTest_P300KS_Facelift",
        "timestamp": "2020-11-28T22:25:20.556145+01:00"
    },
    {
        "deviceId": "Prototype_FieldTest_P300KS_Facelift",
        "timestamp": "2020-11-28T22:25:20.797479+01:00"
    },
    {
        "deviceId": "Prototype_FieldTest_P300KS_Facelift",
        "timestamp": "2020-11-28T22:25:21.041794+01:00"
    },
    {
        "deviceId": "Prototype_FieldTest_P300KS_Facelift",
        "timestamp": "2020-11-28T22:25:21.288214+01:00"
    }
]
```

Comment: Did you try to log the time it takes to save the file? Is it possible that this is what's slowing the code down?

Comment: There is far too much code here to work through. Please update your question with a *much* reduced version which exhibits the time difference you are seeing.

Comment: @BartoszKP No I just tried to measure the time the execution of the function takes and reduced with it time setting for the sleep call. But that´s a good point to look for, because I have to load the file every time to update it with the new entry. I will try it out how the behavior is when I just create files for a minute and combine them to one file before uploading.

Comment: Eliminate drift by keeping a record of the absolute time calculated from when the program started when the next event should happen, and then `sleep`ing only for the time to that absolute time. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50471895/inaccurate-while-loop-timing-in-python/50477494#50477494 - if this doesn’t work then you may need to calibrate your CPU clock because it may be not what you expect.

Comment: @quamrana Sorry that my first post was not so good, I reduced the code just to the function itself where the issue is. And added parts of the function output to show the drift in the time.

Comment: btw I think you meant `once = False` instead of `once = bool`.

Comment: If you have to use sleep and can’t afford its inevitable jitter, then sleep for maybe less than the delay until the next event and then use e.g. looping to achieve the precision you need.

Comment: With your code I think all you may need to do is move `next_call=time.time()` to before the `for` loop, and _don’t_ rebase it using `time.time()` inside the for loop. That will stop the drift but you’ll still have jitter from `sleep()`

Comment: Ok, what you have done seems just fine: The line `next_call = next_call + INTERVAL_TIME` sets a new time in the future and `time.sleep(next_call - time.time())` should shoot for that time taking into account the time now.

Comment: However, you actually have `abs()` in there, which makes me think you put it in there for a reason. Were you experiencing sleep with a negative argument?

Comment: Ok I think I have two issue.  1.) The jitter of the sleep() method   2.) The delay in loading the json file for updating it. Every second  I create 10 entries, each entry has 200 lines of data. Which means after 10 minutes I have 6.000 entries and this cause that every loading of the json file takes longer. <br/>I just tested it with creating more files with less entries and just take a separate thread to combine it to one file

Comment: @barny Would be using ```threading.Event().wait()``` the better approach instead of using ```sleep()``` ?

Comment: Try first to get rid of the drift - to do this you _must not_ rebase next_call using time.time() because that entrenches the drift. Instead start the time reference by reading time.time() before your for loop starts, then always calculate the next_call time by adding INTERVAL_TIME to the previous next_call, and then sleep for `next_call-time.time()` - worth checking if this is negative, it means you spent more than TIME_INTERVAL processing your readings - at least log this and then don’t sleep. So my advice is to fix the drift first.

Comment: Actually also you should change over to using time.perf_counter() because it will give you the best precision.

Comment: It would help if your code were complete [mre] and I could paste it into a file to run it myself _without adding anything_ - so specify the imports, some sample data, etc. And make it minimal, so it just shows the problem with maintaining timing.

Comment: What actually is the value of INTERVAL_TIME? Looks like 100ms in you printout, is that right? Just how accurate do you need to be? If it’s milliseconds or less then you’re likely in for disappointment because Linux is not a realtime OS but you should be able to get within a few tens of milliseconds max jitter and maybe within milliseconds most of the time.

Comment: @barnyThanks for the help, I was able to solve the issue. The main issue was not the jitter of the     sleep()     method, the drift was created by how I added the Data to the json file. I will post an answer with a minimal example of the solution with comparing it to the old one.